# Query External LDAP Server from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows, linked-server, active-directory

I have done extensive research on querying LDAP Server but so far has not been able to work around. Therefore, asking experts help

**Background:** I have a client whose LDAP Server is OnPremise (though facing publicly) and I have a SQL Server(2012 SE) inside the firewall. The communication between the External LDAP and Internal SQL Server are fine as I can ping each other. I also created a remote domain account and used this account when created Linked Server on SQL Server. I also have our internal Domain controller that has Domain Trust Relationship. Now, I have created 2 Linked Servers using Domain account but I have not been able to query LDAP Server on both internally and externally. I hope this is making sense. Anyways, Here are the definitions of my Linked Server and errors I am receiving

**[Solved] Linked Server to an Internal LDAP Server**: This was resolved by using ADuser@domain.com instead of domain/ADuser

```
USE [master]
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ADSI', @srvproduct=N'Active 
Directory Service Interfaces', @provider=N'ADSDSOObject', 
@datasrc=N'adsdatasource'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname=N'ADSI',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,
@rmtuser=N'Domain/ADUser',@rmtpassword='########'
```

Error:

> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT *
>   FROM  'LDAP://Domain.com/OU=Accounts,DC=Domain,DC=com' 
>   --WHERE objectClass =  'User' 
>   " for execution against OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server 
>   "ADSI".

**Linked Server to an External LDAP Server**

```
USE [master]
GO


EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ADSIE', @srvproduct=N'Active 
Directory Service Interfaces', @provider=N'ADSDSOObject', 
@datasrc=N'CustomerIPAdress'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname=N'ADSI',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,
@rmtuser=N'Domain/ADUser',@rmtpassword='########'
```

Error:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSIE" reported an >error. The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to >perform the operation.
>   Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT *
>     FROM 'LDAP://Customer IP Adress'
>     WHERE objectClass = 'User'
>     " for execution against OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server >"ADSIE".

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: One part of it is solved. I am still facing issues when I am querying external LDAP Server. Offcourse, If I resolved it then I will be more than happy to provide the solution.

Comment: Have you considered going with an SSIS package? You may want to take a look at my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594775/error-cannot-fetch-a-row-from-ole-db-provider-adsdsoobject-for-linked-server/9012248#9012248. Also, even if you stick with your current method, there's some good information in the other answers here that may help.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried the solution in the link. However, I have always ended up with "Unable to Build Query" or "Syntax error". I have made sure syntax is fine but I do not know the reason why it still keep throwing those errors

Comment: Are you executing the query against the linked server via a SQL Agent Job step or in a query window using SSMS? If it's being executed in an SSIS SQL Agent Job step, you may have to create a proxy tied to a domain user account that your AD admin has given appropriate rights to read AD. If it's executing in a T-SQL job step you may have to change the job owner. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The error in question above appears when I execute the query from SSMS.

Comment: One thing that I did notice, `@rmtuser=N'Domain/ADUser'` should be `@rmtuser=N'Domain\ADUser'`.

Comment: Verify that Ad Hoc Distributed Queries is enabled on your SQL Server and try querying with OPENROWSET. (See http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3849891/Query-Active-Directory-Data-from-SQL-Server-using-T-SQL.htm) Also, try the query with TOP 100 specified to see if you might be hitting a paging limit. Have your AD admin double-check that the account has the necessary rights in AD for your query.

Comment: Ad Hoc Distributd Queries is enabled. I have tried both OPENROWSET and OPENQUERY with top 10 records but still no luck. I really appreciated your help in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

What stands out the most in your second error message is the message below:

> The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to perform the operation

This tells me that the user in your linked server configuraiton doesn't have access to the AD / LDAP server to perform that query. Here is my ADSI configurations along with an example query. You may need to engage your SA team to ensure the account configured in your linked server has the correct access to query AD / LDAP.

```
    USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  LinkedServer [ADSI]    Script Date: 11/10/2017 3:46:31 PM ******/
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ADSI', @srvproduct=N'Active Directory Services 2.5', @provider=N'ADSDSOObject', @datasrc=N'adsdatasource'
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'ADSI',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'domain\accountname',@rmtpassword='########'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=NULL
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'ADSI', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Here is an example of using the the ADSI linked server using openquery, but you need to understand the OU structure and the domain structure of AD before building the LDAP connection string.

```
SELECT sn, displayName, givenName, mail, telephoneNumber, ipPhone, sAMAccountName
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 
'SELECT sAMAccountName, displayName, telephoneNumber, ipPhone, mail, givenName, sn 
FROM ''LDAP://DC=test,DC=intranet,DC=com'' WHERE objectCategory = ''Person'' AND objectClass = ''user''')
AS derivedtbl_1
```

NOTE: I changed the DC name in the LDAP string for security reasons, but you should be able to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you manage to accomplish `EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver` and `EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin`, you will face another problem: [you won't be able to use `OPENROWSET` or `OPENDATASOURCE` unless you're a database administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/configure-permissions-access-remote-data).

You can create a registry setting on the database server that enables this AdHoc functionality.